# How to enable On-Screen keyboard in samsung galaxy tab emulator in landscape mode?

Tags: android, emulation, on-screen-keyboard, galaxy-tab

I'm facing a problem with the on-screen keyboard in the Samsung Galaxy tab emulator. The on-screen keyboard doesn't show up in landscape mode though it started showing in portrait mode after I enabled "sample soft keyboard" in Language & Keyboard settings.

Comment: Please refer to my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648401/how-to-open-only-half-keyboard-in-landscape-mode/10614766#10614766
for your solution (I believe it will work in the emulator as well as it does on the actual devices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Galaxy Tab emulator using Samsung's provided AVD files does NOT properly display the keyboard in landscape mode. If you look closely when you click a field to edit you'll notice a grey couple of pixels appear at the bottom of your application, this signifies the keyboard coming up but it is obviously not drawing properly. It displays in portrait mode just fine.

You can still use your computer's keyboard in the emulator to enter your text and the keyboard does definitely display just fine on the real device in horizontal mode so don't stress about your code being incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Holding the Home key will cause the keyboard to appear regardless of that context.

Does that work?  Or does the keyboard simply never appear for you? :(

Comment: Holding down the home key opens a list of most recently used applications :(

Comment: That's right, I'm sorry - I meant the menu key.  I think it's to the left of Home on the Galaxy Tab.