# How to open only half keyboard in Landscape mode?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to develop an Android typing based game. I would really want this game to work on landscape mode, because, in my opinion, it is more specific Android games.

There it is this first problem

if I toggle landscape mode, when the user opens the keyboard he can not see the rest of the screen because in Landscape Mode it opens Full Screen. (my keyboard does this)

**Question**: Is there any way in which I can open only half keyboard in Landscape Mode so that the user can see what where he is typing or does anyone find another way to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This does e.g. not happen on a tablet with a swiftkey keyboard.. in the extreme case you can implement your own software keyboard (input control..)

Comment: I dont know exactly how, but some applications does this, for example, the browser while writing to forms.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I can't tell how can you implement your own keyboard but I will try and search. I don't want the user to be forced to download a keyboard or something like this. I await further answers to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding this:

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

to your EditText node (in the xml) will make it so that the keyboard pops up on half the screen and lets you edit the text right IN the text field (in your UI) rather than in its own (full screen) text edit area.

I've just tested this in a Galaxy Nexus (running ICS) and a RAZR Maxx (running Gingerbread), the app is compiled for midSdk 10 (2.3.3).  It appears to work.

Comment: Dr.Dredel, I don't have an EditText that shows the keyboard. I am showing the keyboard using InputMethodManager. The problem is not that the keyboard would obstruct the whole view (I see only the keyboard, without the "text entry area" which is described in the linked issue), but that the view is not 'height adjusted' so part of it is unsable because I can not scroll it.

Comment: @miha, I'm not sure what you're describing. Also, what does that have to do with the original question above?