# when my appllication goes into landscape view all goes wrong

Tags: android

when i go into landscape view all looks good eg. you see. "Licence Type" and then a box to type in. however when the person goes to type into the box the view changes some how and you cant see the "Licence Type" just a button that when clicked on goes to the next box with no description this mean the person has no idea what they are doing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SaveBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="SaveBtn_Click"
        android:text="@string/SaveStr" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BackBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/BackStr" />

</TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/LicenceTypeStr"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TypeEt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:hint="@string/LicenceTypeHintStr"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/LicenceNumberStr"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NumberEt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/LicenceNumberHintStr"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
  // .. more rowws

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ExpiryDateEt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/FrontImgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/FrontImgStr" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="300dip"
android:layout_height="200dip"
/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BackImgBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/BackImageStr" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_width="300dip"
android:layout_height="200dip"
/>

</TableLayout>
```

the view is in layout mode as i have found this to be the best way of getting a photo and manipulate it then display it and not loose it.
I must be missing something.
If someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr. Dredel was wright.
Howerver this method alone did not fix my problem as in the notes i got 3/4 of the screen visable. His answer did give me the path to the anser.

android:imeOptions="actionDone"

In each EditText field.

This is also a Duplicate Question as he said but i will leave it as my answer may help others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you don't want the keyboard to take over the entire screen when in landscape.

Check out my answer here, it will work for you as well (and this is technically a duplicate of the same problem)

[How to open only half keyboard in Landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648401/how-to-open-only-half-keyboard-in-landscape-mode)

Comment: pitty i cant do a screen shot i get the keyboar to fill 3/4 of the screen. so i cant see any textbox at all